# Sorting options within a select element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to sort the `option`s within a `SELECT` element. I wonder if I am doing it stupidly or not, so perhaps someone can look at it and provide suggestions.

```
// Function Name            = sortSelect(jsID, tagAttr)
// Function Purpose         = Sort elements within a select element by supplying the ID of the select element. Sorting parameter is based on the order of the tags passed in through tagAttr as an array with decreasing importance. CSS styles can be use as a sort parameters as well with syntax css:
// Example Call             = sortSelect("element", ["css: display", "id"]);

function sortSelect(jsID, tagAttr) {
    var jqID = "#"+jsID;
    var arrHold = [];
    var arrTemp = [];
    var arrObjs = [];
    var ct;
    var comp;

    if ($(jqID).prop("tagName").toUpperCase() == "SELECT") {
        $(jqID + " option").each(function() {
            arrHold = [];
            arrHold.push($(this));

            for (var j in tagAttr) {
                if (tagAttr[j].replace(/\s+/g, '').substring(0, 4) !== "css:") {
                    arrHold.push($(this).attr(tagAttr[j]));
                } else {
                    arrHold.push($(this).css(tagAttr[j].replace(/\s+/g, '').substring(4, tagAttr[j].length).trim()));
                }

                j+=1;
            }

            arrTemp.push(arrHold);
            ct+=1;
        });

        if (ct < $("#"+jsID).childElementCount) {
            var message = "Nodes other than 'option' has been detected, and may have been lost!"
            console.warn(message);
        }

        arrTemp = arrTemp.sort(function(a,b) {
            for (i=1; i<=tagAttr.length; i++) {
                comp = (''+a[i]).localeCompare(b[i]);

                if (comp != 0) {
                    return comp;
                }
            }

            return 0;
        }); 

        for (i=0; i < arrTemp.length; i++) {
            arrObjs.push(arrTemp[i][0]);
        }

        $(jqID).empty();
        $(jqID).append(arrObjs);
    }
}
```